# .text () and .html() not working in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using jquery function

```
       $("#btn1").click(function(){
            $("p").text("")
       }
```

Whenever I click the button the `.text()` field is not loading and When I update `.text` value into small string it works.

Comment: its not clear wat you are asking. Can you please show the code snippet or share it in fiddle

Comment: what are you trying? trying to get the text or set the text?

Comment: `.text("")` will clear text from `p`. What are you trying to do.

Comment: I got what he want! he want to get `p` text after click the button. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jiffiddle/ofxvn00x/)

Comment: .text(" ")  function is only loading smaller strings values but not loading bigger strings values.

Comment: try .html() insted of text()

Answer (score 0):

```
 $("#btn1").click(function()
  {
           var mytext=$("p").html(); // for getting
          var mytext=$("p").html("mytext value"); // for setting

   });
```

you have to that give closing brace  " ); "

Answer (score 0):

try this.this will show your text in alert when you click your button.just copy,paste and try it.hope this will help to you

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <title></title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 </head>

<body>
  <p>Govinda</p><br/>
  <button id="click">show text</button>

   <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
   <h2></h2>
   <button id="addtext">Add text</button>

   
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#click").click(function(){
     var pText = $("p").text();
        alert("this is the paragraph text :"+ pText);
    });

    $("#addtext").click(function(){
     var addT = "Added Text";
        $("h2").text(addT);
    });


 
  });
</script>


</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.Unfortunately,i am trying to add string greater than 70 so when i click the button Add text the desired string does not show up.By the way i am trying to add lorem ipsum the dummy text.Thank you again!